# Products in Shopping cart are not shown after pressing Page refresh

Tags: php, opencart, shopping-cart, jscript

I have implemented flytocart to opencart. ( i.e. after i click on addtocart button, a small 15 X 15 picture flies to location of shopping cart and stays there.) However, this small picture is only visible till I do not press Enter or navigate to another page. Basically, I want the product item pictures once added to cart should remain displayed till Checkout.

Comment: Are you requesting `index.php?route=checkout/cart/add` within your AJAX call? Are the products really added to the cart? From what I understand your solution implements only the JS part while not invoking the PHP side for adding the products into the cart in the end...

Comment: Right. I've just done the JS part. Products fly into cart - just like www.zopnow.com. So far, I could only managed to let the products fly. Can you please elaborate more on the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the picture location in a session variable.. Use it whenever the page reloads.

```
    $_SESSION["pic"][ ]="image.jpg"
```

In this way the image name will be stored till logout. If you wanna remove it before that you can use unset function to remove it. Also you can store multiple image names in it.

```
    $_SESSION["pic"][0]="image1.jpg";
    $_SESSION["pic"][1]="image2.jpg";
    $_SESSION["pic"][2]="image3.jpg";
```